# Android permission of creating database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-manifest

Hi I have some problems in creating the sqlite database in android.

Everything is ok on the emulator, I can create the database. But it doesn't work on the actually machine. When I tried to debug the application on my phone, it just failed to create the database.

So can anyone tell my what happened? Is there any special permission I need to add in the Manifest file? I've tried ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES or WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, but still cannot get the database.

By the way, is the custom database can only be stored in the sd card but the root directory?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Read the logcat. It will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: This sample application demonstrates working with a database, and it works on emulators and devices: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Database/Constants

Comment: Thank you very much, everyone. I have solved it already. The problem is that the emulator does not require the extension of ".db" while the actual handset does require it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Without any feedback in the error, it is impossible to tell you what's wrong in your code. Nevertheless, I can tell you that you do **not** need `ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES` for using your own database. You should not need `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` either unless you are trying to access the sdcard.

The databases are stored by default in a subfolder of your app folder in the internal storage, i.e.:

```
/data/data/YOUR_APP/databases/YOUR_DATABASAE.db
```

If you do that on a physical device it has to be rooted though.

Comment: @Aleadam Thank you, Aleadam. Neither the permission works here. The problem is that without these permissions on emulator, I can create the database and get the record by using the cursor. I just cannot make it on my phone. So could you please tell me why?

Comment: @Kitten no, I cannot. For the same reason than yesterday: **you need to read the logcat**. See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html or check the debug perspective in Eclipse.

Comment: @Aleadam Thank you all the same! Have a nice day!!

Comment: @Kitten I did not mean that we cannot help, I meant just that we need more info! The logcat is a very powerful tool and one that you should dreally learn how to use if you want to develop android apps. Please, take the time to read about it, and then use it with your app. Then, you can post another question then with the logcat stack trace and that, together with a short description of the problem and a short code snippet, will most probably be enough to find the problem. Good luck!

Comment: @Aleadam Thank you! The log shows that it cannot query because there is no certain table in the database. **bold**However, it just happens on the real mobile, not emulator. In the emulator, the code works fine.**bold** So I wonder whether there is any permission that prevents the app from accessing the internal storage.

Comment: @Kitten, no it means that you don't have a table in the phone that you are trying to read (maybe you did not create it in the phone?). If it were a permissions problem, it would clearly say so.

Comment: @Aleadam Yeah, that's why I was confused. The same code is applicable on the emulator. Maybe I should store the database into the sd card.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem. My application would create a db on the emulator, read and write data, but it crashed when on the device.

I found a very simple solution to this: delete the database on your device manually at /data/data/YOUR_APP/databases/YOUR_DATABASAE.db and then rerun your app.

Worked in my case, hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

It's  very easy to solve You must have not added .db extension in your DataBase Name declared in the db java file
For eg, `public static final String DB_NAME = "tasks.db";`

DON'T FORGET THE .db EXTENSION

Comment: It does not matter. The database name can be almost anything.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have this problem because you have a prevoius version of your app installed on your phone. Before you install the new version try to uninstall the previous by "Application Manager". I solve in this way.

Answer (score 0):

at the first I check permissions and runtime get permission, but since the targetSdkVersion was 25, the problem was unsolved,
work with db without use EXTENSION of .db always be good and worked, but its looks that targetSdkVersion of 25 need the EXTENSION of .db
and my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have cleared the app data from applications from settings, then uninstall and run the app with renaming the db file with .db extension, it works for me