# Spelling checker in java for Android

Tags: java, android, spelling

I have a dictionary of about 40,000 words. In the past I have used it as a text file that I have read in and used it to check spelling of user words. However, I want to read it from a class, not a text file, so I don't have to ask for permission to do so. I would like, if possible, for all the words to be elements of an array (or list) in one java class. However, I get an exceeding limit error. What I don't understand is why I don't get that error if I read all the words from a file and store them in an array (as I have done in other java programs for desktop computers). It is the same set of words. 
    I realise I am not publishing actual code, but just pasting thousands of words in the form of "ma", "macabre", "macaroni", "mace", "maced", "maces", "machete", etc. seems pretty pointless.
    I don't want to use someone else's word list because I am aiming at young children and my list has 'four letter words' removed, etc.
    Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: thats a lot of code.. adding each word to the array without using a file or server

Comment: Can you explain in more detail about "exceeding limit error"?

Comment: The code of constructor MyDictionary2() is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit -- this is the error when I have split the dictionary into smaller parts. If it is in bigger parts I get an exceed constant error. It could be read only because I want it to be part of a class, not a file that is read in.

Comment: Is there any reason that you don't want to use a file, other than it requiring permission? Because you could store it as a resource in res/raw and you wouldn't require any permissions.

Comment: I wasn't aware I could store it as a resource without requiring a permission to read/write. Thanks for that.

Comment: No probs. If it helps, here is some more info [adding resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) and also [accessing resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html)

Comment: Thanks. This answers the question. However, I can't work out how to say it does. Sorry about my lack of knowledge.

Comment: @user184994, you should probably make these comments an answer.

Comment: @David Conrad No probs, I've added them as an answer below.

Comment: How? I would like to say this question is answered, but I just can't work out how to do so.

Comment: I'd better use a **database** for such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only issue is permissions, you should consider storing the file as a resource, within the `res/raw` directory. This will not require any permissions, although it means the file will be read-only.

There is more information about [providing resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) and [accessing resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html) in the Android documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `SQLite`, and its build-it searching functions for spelling checker. As it states [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165887/android-permission-of-creating-database) you dont need any special permission to use a database.