# how to use run time permissions for database in android

Tags: android

I have problem with runtime permission for database.I dont know how use and write permissions for my code. and I very search but at lost to understand.
the code is:

```
public class G  {
public static Context        context;
public static SQLiteDatabase database;
public static final String   DIR_SDCARD   = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
public static final String   DIR_DATABASE = DIR_SDCARD + "/database-test";
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = this.getApplicationContext();
   // new File(DIR_DATABASE).mkdirs();
    File file=new File(DIR_DATABASE);
    file.mkdirs();
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DIR_DATABASE + "/database.sqlite", null);
    database.execSQL("CREATE  TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS person (person_name TEXT NOT NULL ," +
                " person_family TEXT NOT NULL , " +
                " person_password TEXT NOT NULL   )");
}
```

}
please help me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6168988/2459628

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android permission of creating database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165887/android-permission-of-creating-database)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Android run-time permissions for your own database in Android. All you are gonna do is create the database and do some CRUD operations on it.

The database resides inside your app's allocated space so that does not need any permissions. However if you are going to read/Write to sdCard then you might need those run time permissions.

You can find a detailed documentation right here,

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: is this statement fully still valid? recent updates to my code is asking for additional permissions!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) is a very good guide to request permissions at run time. Basically, the code for checking and asking for the permission is:

> ```
> // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
> if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
>                 Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
>         != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
>
>     // Should we show an explanation?
>     if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
>             Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
>
>         // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
>         // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
>         // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
>
>     } else {
>
>         // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
>
>         ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
>                 new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
>                 MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
>
>         // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
>         // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
>         // result of the request.
>     }
> }
> ```

Then, you get the results at:

> ```
> @Override
> public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
>         String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
>     switch (requestCode) {
>         case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
>             // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
>             if (grantResults.length > 0
>                 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
>
>                 // permission was granted, yay! Do the
>                 // contacts-related task you need to do.
>
>             } else {
>
>                 // permission denied, boo! Disable the
>                 // functionality that depends on this permission.
>             }
>             return;
>         }
>
>         // other 'case' lines to check for other
>         // permissions this app might request
>     }
> }
> ```